# Spring boot app setting specific java version in systemd unit

Tags: java, spring-boot, systemd

I have installed my runnable jar as a systemd service but its not picking up my jvm options I set in my .conf file. My jar and conf file are located in the same folder. I have to use a conf file to get external configuration in place for different setups. I have specified the java path because we run java 8 as default for other java services on the same host.

Systemd Unit

```
[Unit]
Description="My service"
After=syslog.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myfolder/my-app-folder

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.7.10-4.el7_8.x86_64/bin"
User=my-user

ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.7.10-4.el7_8.x86_64/bin/java -jar /opt/myfolder/my-app-folder/myapp.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Conf file

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/my-app -Dspring.profiles.active=test -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dloader.path=lib"
RUN_ARGS="--management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `EnvironmentFile=` and point it to your config. From the question you make it seem like you want to start the application and the read the config but that doesn't make sense.

Also, don't use full path to JDK, I think in your case you'd be better off using `/etc/alternatives/jre_11_openjdk` - it links to the same place but if you update package version you won't get an error on service start/restart/etc.